# pyspark groupByKey's Iterable object (ResultIterable) what are the advantages of this?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, iterable

I'm not finding anything helpful on line regards to the result structure after the `groupByKey` transformation.  What can I do with the `ResultIterable` object after `groupByKey`?  I would have expected a list returned with the key.  I can convert it to a list but not sure if I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the advantages of this?

[Serialization](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/python/pyspark/resultiterable.py#L26-L27)

> ```
> A special result iterable. This is used because the standard
> iterator can not be pickled
> ```

> What can I do with the "ResultIterable"

The same things you can do  with any `Iterable` object:

> ```
> class ResultIterable(collections.Iterable):
> ```

[specifically you can assume](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) that it implements [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) dunder method - it means it can be iterated or converted to another collection and can be used whenever iterable objects is expected.

> I would have expected a list

`list` requires specific implementation of the collection. `Iterable` allows other options, including larger than memory collections, and specific implementation  can be change whenever needed.